# RStudio: colnames() function not showing name of very first column

Tags: r

When I run `colnames()`, it never shows the name of this first column.
For example, after wasting a lot of time researching online, I discovered the name of the first column in `mtcars` is `das_Auto`.

Why doesn't this name show when I run this code?
`[colnames(mtcars)][1]`

What's the easiest way to determine the name of the first column in a data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the first 'column' of `mtcars` is not actually a column but an index. If you want to convert it to a column you can run the below:

```
df <- cbind(das_Auto = rownames(mtcars), mtcars)
rownames(df) <- 1:nrow(mtcars)

head(df)
           das_Auto  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1         Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3        Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6           Valiant 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```